# For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that $\tau(n^2)=\sum_{d|n}{2^{a(d)}}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $a(n)$ denotes the number of distinct prime divisors of $n >1$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that $\tau(n^2)=\sum_{d|n}{2^{a(d)}}$.

My attempt: Prime factorisation of $n$ is $\prod_{i=1}^k{p_i^{e_i}}$. This implies that $\tau(n^2)=\prod_{i=1}^k{(2e_i +1)}$. Since $d|n$ and $\gcd(p_i^{e_i},p_j^{e_j})=1$ for $i \neq j$, $d_i|p_i^{e_i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$. Hence, $$\sum_{d|n}{2^{a(d)}=\sum_{d_i|p_i^{e_i},1 \leq i \leq k}2^{a(d)}}$$

I stuck at here. I don know how to relate. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function on the left, $\tau(n^2)$, is multiplicative. Check that $2^{a(n)}$ is multiplicative as well, and [therefore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function#Convolution) so is $\sum_{d\mid n}2^{a(d)}$. This reduces the problem to the case $n=p^e$, and this case is immediate.